# Python: How do you take a random word (if the word itself is also random) out of a file?

Tags: python, file, readline, pytube

My first question so I'll simplify it.
So I have a txt file that breaks down audio files:

```
 <Stream: itag="249"; mime_type="audio/webm" abr="50kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
 <Stream: itag="250"; mime_type="audio/webm" abr="70kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
 <Stream: itag="251"; mime_type="audio/webm" abr="160kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
```

I wanted to take all `itag="{n}";` out and print them. My preferred output is:

```
itag="249"
itag="250"
itag="251"
```

But the thing is, `{n}` will be different for the 3 itags everytime the user provides different audio. Here's the code I tried:

```
with open(report_file) as file_obj:
    for line in file_obj:
        disk_read=''.join(map(str, open(report_file).readline()))
        index=disk_read.find(';')
        return disk_read[:index]+disk_read[disk_read.find('\n'):]
```

But the output is:

```
 <Stream: itag="249"
```

and the rest just disappeared. Any help would be very appreciated!
EDIT: Thank you not_speshal! Case closed, thank you everyone

Comment: `return` returns from the function. You might want to gather all findings in a list and return that list after the loop.

Comment: so what you mean by that is to convert the text file into a list and then just slice them? I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def parse(report_file):
    itags = list()
    with open(report_file) as file_obj:
        for line in file_obj:
            itags.append(line.split(";")[0].split(":")[-1].strip())
    return itags

>>> parse("test.txt")
['itag="249"', 'itag="250"', 'itag="251"']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by string.split(separator, maxsplit)

```
with open(report_file) as file_obj:
    tag = []
    for line in file_obj:
        text = line.split(";")
        text = text[0].split(": ")
        tag.append(text[-1])
    return tag
```

Comment: it returned with ' itag="135" '. The last 2 itags are still missing. Do I need a loop maybe?

Comment: still only returns the first "itag" hhhhhhhhh

Answer (score 0):

you should just be able to slice the string

```
with open(report_file) as file_obj:
    for line in file_obj:
        disk_read=''.join(map(str, open(report_file).readline(line)))
        index=disk_read.find(';')
        return disk_read[8:index]+disk_read[disk_read.find('\n'):]
```

Comment: that is a lot better than my code, but the last 2 are still missing :(

Comment: sorry, last two what?

Comment: the last two itags, "itag="250"" and "itag="251""

Comment: the results are still the same sadly